# How do i recall a string into a quote?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with recalling the name of a person that was previously entered into the program with a cout statement.

```
int main()
{
string donorName;
string donorGender;
int donorWeight;
int donorHeight;
int donorAge;


cout << "What is the donor's name?" << endl;

getline(cin, donorName);

if (donorAge < 16)
    {
        cout << "--- No, **(name)** you cannot donate blood" << endl;
    }
```

Can you help me how I can put "No, "donor Name" you can not donate blood into the cout statement from the name they put in for donor name?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Who said you need to embed it *into* the literal?

Comment: `cout << "--- No, \"" << donorName << "\" you cannot donate blood" << endl;`

Comment: So are you essentially asking how to represent a `"` character within a character array literal? As shown in my comment above you can do that using a `\ ` before the `"`. This is very basic, and should be covered by any beginners textbook already. Thus I'm not writing that as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for string interpolation like for example in PHP or in TypeScript, where you can conveniently write:

```
const my_variable = 123;
const text = `some text ... ${my_variable} ...`;
```

Unfortunately, C++ doesn't have such a feature. There has been a [proposal for it](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/Yr9Zmrze2sg), but I don't think it ever got anywhere.

If the goal is just to print the text, then the safest and easiest way to do so is to split the literal into two parts and print them separately, along with the variable in between:

```
std::cout << "--- No, " << donorName << ", you cannot donate blood\n";
```